# Exporting attributes from QGIS to TXTF file using Python

Tags: python, pyqgis, export, qgis-processing, attributeerror

I have used this method outlined in:
https://howtoinqgis.wordpress.com/2016/10/31/how-to-export-attributes-from-qgis-to-a-txt-file/

```py
##input_file=vector
 
from qgis.core import *
import processing

# Load the layer
layer = processing.getObject(input_file)
 
# Set the path for the output file
output_file = open('C:/.../cities.txt', 'w')
 
# Get the features and properly rewrite them as lines
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    msgout = '%s, %s\n' % (feat["name"], feat["pop_max"])
    unicode_message = msgout.encode('utf-8')
    output_file.write(unicode_message)
output_file.close()
```

It works with QGIS 2.18, but it throws an error in QGIS 3 because "processing.getObject":

```
AttributeError: module 'processing' has no attribute 'getObject'
```

Do you know if there is a replacement for QGIS 3?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about `pyqgis` but you can easily accomplish this using `ogr` which is included in the QGIS Python installation:

```
import ogr

# define input shapefile and output txt
input_fn = r'path/to/input.shp'
output_fn = r'path/to/output.txt'

# open shapefile and get layer definition
ds = ogr.Open(input_fn, 0)
lyr = ds.GetLayer(0)
lyr_dfn = lyr.GetLayerDefn()

# get field names
fields = []
for n in range(lyr_dfn.GetFieldCount()):
    field_dfn = lyr_dfn.GetFieldDefn(n)
    fields.append(field_dfn.name)

# open output file in writing mode
with open(output_fn, 'w') as f:

    # write file header (field names)
    f.write(','.join(fields) + '\n')

    # loop through each feature and its fields and write them to the file
    for ind, feat in enumerate(lyr):
        values = []
        for i in range(lyr_dfn.GetFieldCount()):
            values.append(feat.GetField(i))
        values = list(map(lambda x: str(x), values))  # convert all values to strings
        f.write(','.join(values) + '\n')

# close shapefile
del ds
```

Comment: YES!!!! it works :) Thanks